# Capture JavaScript Popup text in webBrowser C#

Tags: javascript, c#

I have a webBrowser control on my C# forms app,which works perfectly.
However, the url I am navigating to has JavaScript popups with text on them during interaction.

How do I capture the text on the JavaScript popup boxes?
For example, the alert says "no more food" I want to capture the text "no more food" and pass to a label .
below is my click event code and OnDocumentCompleted event handler

```
 private void iTalk_Button_21_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //click event
    {
        Username = username.Text.Trim();
        Password=password.Text.Trim();
         webBrowser1.Navigate("someurl");
        webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted;

        //MessageBox.Show(Username);
    }

    private void WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        tabControl1.SelectedTab = tabPage2;
        HtmlDocument doc = this.webBrowser1.Document;
        doc.GetElementById("ctl00_MainContent_Login1_UserName").SetAttribute("Value", Username);
        doc.GetElementById("ctl00_MainContent_Login1_Password").SetAttribute("Value", Password);
        doc.GetElementById("ctl00_MainContent_Login1_LoginButton").InvokeMember("click");
    }
```

Comment: Well, it seems you did it there. Use the DOM to extract the information you're looking for.

Comment: Is a JavaScript alert box part of the DOM? Since it gets fired after a particular event, like say a button click,I don't think I can access it via the DOM . Please  elaborate. Thanks

Comment: Oh, I thought you meant like jQuery popups, not alerts. Alerts are not part of the DOM. However, you may be able to "trick" the system if you are able to inject scripts into the page. You can would be able to use a proxy method by overriding the `window.alert` function and make this information available somewhere in your page.